# Plotting functions with a varying parameter whose range depends on said parameter

Tags: plotting

I'm fairly new to Mathematica so I'm not sure how I can achieve this, I've tried a number of ways but nothing has worked so far.
I basically want to plot a function r against n for different parameter values of f but with the line segmented into f dependent regions of different colours,

```
Mp = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "PlanckMass"], "Gigaelectronvolts/c^2"];
\[HBar] = UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckConstant"], "SI"];
As = 2.196*10^(-9);
T0 = Quantity[6.626*10^(-13), "GeV/c^2"];
gre = 100;
k0 = UnitConvert[
    UnitConvert[ Quantity[0.05, 1/"Megaparsecs"], "SI"]*\[HBar]*
     UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"], "SI"], 
    "Gigaelectronvolts"]/Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]^2;

Nk[f_, n_] := -(f/
     Mp)^2 Log[(1 + Mp^2/(2 f^2)) (((1 - n) - Mp^2/f^2)/((1 - n) + 
      Mp^2/f^2))]
H[f_, n_] := \[Pi] Mp Sqrt[2 As ((1 - n) - Mp^2/f^2)]
Ve[f_, n_] := 
 3 H[f, n]^2 Mp^2 *((1 + (1 - n) (f/Mp)^2)/(2 + 4 (f/Mp)^2))

Nr[n_, wre_, f_] := 
 4/(1 - 3*wre) (61.6 - Log[Ve[f, n]^(1/4)/H[f, n]] - Nk[f, n]);
Tre[n_, wre_, 
   f_] := ((43/(11*gre))^(1/3)*T0/k0*H[f, n]*
     Exp[-Nk[f, n]]*((3^2*5 Ve[f, n])/(\[Pi]^2*gre))^(-1/(
       3 (1 + wre))))^((3 (1 + wre))/(3 wre - 1));

r[f_,n_]:= 4 ((1 - n) - Mp^2/f^2)
```

However, I want to colour the regions between these values different colours

```
nr0[f_] := Re[n /. FindRoot[Nr[n, 0, f] == 70, {n, 0.97}]]
nr1[f_] := Re[n /. FindRoot[Nr[n, 1, f] == 70, {n, 0.97}]]
nr13[f_] := 
 Re[n /. FindRoot[
    Log[Ve[f, n]^(1/4)/H[f, n]] + Nk[f, n] == 61.6 , {n, 0.95}]]
```

I then made four functions with the ranges given above,

```
g1[f_] := 
 Plot[r[f, n], {n, 0.93, nr0[f]}, PlotRange -> {{0.93, 1}, {0, 0.25}},
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thickness[0.02]}]
g2[f_] := Plot[r[f, n], {n, nr0[f], nr13[f]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.93, 1}, {0, 0.25}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}]
g3[f_] := Plot[r[f, n], {n, nr13[f], nr1[f]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.93, 1}, {0, 0.25}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Thickness[0.02]}]
g4[f_] := Plot[r[f, n], {n, nr1[f], 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.93, 1}, {0, 0.25}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Thickness[0.02]}]
```

For a fixed value of f I used the Show function to give:

```
Mp = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "PlanckMass"], "Gigaelectronvolts/c^2"];

Show[g1[100 Mp], g2[100 Mp], g3[100 Mp], g4[100 Mp]]
```

[image]

However, I want to be able to plot this for different values of f where the colour range depends on the value of f. In particular I want to plot a range of f from say 10 Mp to 100 Mp. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Edit your question to include the definitions for your functions (e.g., `Nr`, `Ve`, `H`, `Nk`). Always include all code and data for a minimal working example so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, just edited in the missing code

Comment: The function `Nr` is still undefined.

Comment: @BobHanlon Ah yes sorry about that. It's all complete now

Answer (score 0):

```
fValues = {"100Mp", "30Mp", "20Mp", "15Mp", "12Mp", "10Mp"};

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[r[f, n], {f, ToExpression@fValues}],
 {n, 0.93, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{0.93, 1}, {0, 0.25}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {n, HoldForm@r[f, n]}),
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[fValues,
    LegendLabel -> Style[f, 14],
    LegendFunction ->
     (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4,
        FrameStyle -> Gray,
        Background -> White] &)], 
   {.847, .659}],
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For segmented lines

```
funcs =
  Flatten[
   Table[
    With[{fv = ToExpression[f]},
     Tooltip[ConditionalExpression[r[fv, n], #], f] & /@
      {0.93 < n < 
        nr0[fv],
       nr0[fv] < n < nr13[fv],
       nr13[fv] < n < nr1[fv],
       nr1[fv] < n < 1}],
    {f, fValues}],
   1];

Plot[Evaluate@funcs, {n, 0.93, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red, Yellow, Green},
 PlotRange -> {{0.93, 1}, {0, 0.25}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {n, HoldForm@r[f, n]}),
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Epilog -> {Arrow[{{.99, .1}, {.99, .13}}],
   Text["increasing f", {.99, .09}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I want to be able to plot that but have each line segmented into Orange, Red, Yellow and Green by the values nr0[f], nr13[f], nr1[f].